# What does the abbreviation "abwert." mean?

Tags: abbreviation

I have been seeing the abbreviation *abwert.* quite often, and it seems to be unique to an online dictionary I am using. There is no glossary for the abbreviations I can refer to, and I can't seem to find its meaning by googling it. See below for an example:

> Kauz  der Kauz SUBST
>   1. in verschiedenen Arten vorkommender, zu den Eulen gehörender Vogel
>   2. umg. **abwert.** seltsamer, sonderbarer Mann Er ist schon ein komischer Kauz.

I would appreciate if someone could enlighten me about what this means. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This wiktionary article about the abbreviation "abwert."](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/abwert.) is at least in my google results the fourth entry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**abwert.** is an abbreviation for *abwertend*, thus *derogatory*.

Answer (score 1):

The quoted reference "umg. abwert. apparently refers to "Umgangssprache abwertend" = in collegial language = Common language downgrading.

Comment: The important sentence is the last one of the long paragraph. The rest does not answer the question.

Comment: Das Kürzel "umg." bedeutet wohl "umgangssprachlich"; würde es "Umgangsprache" heißen müsste es "Umg." abgekürzt werden und es sollte dann vielleicht auch ein Komma danach stehen.